# Change all positive values in array to 1 (Python)

Tags: python, arrays

So I have several 3D arrays that I need to add together. Each array consists of entries with either 0 or 1. All arrays also have the same dimension. Now, when I add these arrays together some of the values overlap (which they do). However, I just need to know how the structure of the total combined array is, which means that I don't need the values 1, 2 or 3 when 2 or 3 arrays have overlapped. This also just need to be one, and of course, wherever there is a zero, the value zero just need to remain zero.

So basically what I have is:

```
array1 = 
[[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
[[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
[[0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0]]]

array2 = 
[[[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
[[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]]]
```

So when adding them together I get:

```
array_total = array1 + array2 = 
[[[2, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
[[0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
[[0, 0, 2], [1, 2, 1], [0, 0, 0]]]
```

Where I actually want it to give me:

```
array_total = array1 + array2 = 
[[[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
[[0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
[[0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0]]]
```

So can anyone give me a hint to how this is done ?

Comment: So, those are `numpy` arrays?

Comment: With numpy arrays, `array1 | array2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Assuming those are `numpy` arrays, or `array1 + array2` would behave differently).

If you want to "change all positive values to 1", you can do this

```
array_total[array_total > 0] = 1
```

But what you actually want is an array that has a `1` where `array1` or `array2` has a `1`, so just write it directly like that:

```
array_total = array1 | array2
```

Example:

```
>>> array1 = np.array([[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
... [[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
... [[0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0]]])
>>> array2 = np.array([[[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]], 
... [[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
... [[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]]])
>>> array1 | array2
array([[[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
       [[0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
       [[0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0]]])
```

Comment: Ah, yes, they are numpy arrays. But thank you, I did not know about the | operator.